# How can you prevent the camera from colliding with ALL objects in the scene in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In threejs, I have made a scene using threejs editor. How can I prevent the camera from moving inside of the bounds of all of these objects?

Eg

```
scene = importwhatever;
camera.setUpCollision(scene.objects)
```

I am making a game with wasd controls, and that is why I need this.

Comment: Camera collision algorithms are very complicated. Search for a library that can do this.

Comment: I have search for some and I have found [this](https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls), but it is typescript, and my project cannot be typescript. Any ideas?